# Resize div according to viewport (JQuery or JS solution only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to resize a scrollable-div according to the viewport, so that it maintains 100% height and 100% width inside its parent container when resized. This includes maintaining a scrollbar inside the div at all time. So...

**Is it possible to resize a div to 100% height & width of the parent container depending on the size of the viewport?**

My main problem so far has to do with a toggle content button that adds a 
space on top of the scrollable-div, but instead of the div adjusting it gets 
pushed down until the bottom scroll-button gets cut off. Is there 
a way to resize it dynamically with the scrollbar?

**UPDATE:** This is the code I'm focusing on the center section. The #content and #contentsection are the scrollable div and the content, and their parent containers are #networkfeed, #feed-content, and .center

```
  <!--Center-->
        <div class="center">

         <!--Feed Content-->
         <div id="feed-content">
         <div id="networkfeed" class="feedpagetab activefeed"> 


 <input onclick="toggleContent()" type="checkbox" id="filterbutton" role="button">
         <label for="filterbutton" onclick=""><span class="filterswitch">Show Me</span><span class="filterswitch">Hide Me</span> 
          </label>

 <div class="borderline"></div>
     <div id="content"></div><!--Filtercontent ends here-->
            <div id="contentSection">
            <div id="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius an dolorum lucilius sensibus, et sint graeco nec. Iudico atomorum eam eu. Nec equidem conceptam id. Cum velit viris voluptua an. Sea eu harum eirmod eloquentiam, quaestio complectitur voluptatibus in nam, an dicam platonem adolescens has. Te usu esse idque, no modo tractatos sed. Vero audire sapientem an sit, homero recteque pri in, vis at vidit admodum. Ex quo doctus eleifend contentiones, vis odio mucius tritani ut. Id cetero nostrud dissentiunt mel. Docendi scaevola vis ei. Vel et ponderum electram expetendis, cum cu quaestio definitionem, etiam ponderum vix ei. Ut his feugait assentior philosophia, atqui definitionem at mei. Liber sonet dictas ea has, nec odio fabellas ei. Vel oratio quodsi in, duo minim admodum ea. Pri id dolorum indoctum, vim at alia tritani. No pro esse error solet, vix quis prodesset ei. Tollit accommodare vis at, sed in tamquam prompta dolorem. Nam solum definitionem an, dicta nostrum adversarium ne nec. Eu docendi nominavi similique pri. Qui an natum tamquam, dictas invenire mei id. Cu omittam insolens rationibus ius, dicunt inciderint cum ea. Est vero dolorem et, assum antiopam mea ne. Te vel choro audiam, eum equidem nostrum ex. Ea nam offendit definitiones. In etiam debitis similique cum. Ius regione incorrupte te, utinam ceteros an has, omnium concludaturque cum eu. Eu sumo adhuc ius. Quo choro quodsi latine an. Nonumy deleniti duo ex, fastidii menandri accusata ut mea, ad minimum omnesque quo. Cum in molestiae mediocritatem. Partiendo voluptaria cum te. Illud reque convenire duo et, audiam denique consectetuer mei te. Bonorum fabellas interpretaris mel ad. Eu sanctus nominavi ius, oratio vocibus indoctum ea eos. Et nisl doming vituperatoribus vis. Ullum percipit inciderint ei duo, ex usu stet essent. Quis errem legere ex quo, usu ludus decore ut, vix cetero convenire honestatis et. Mucius nusquam platonem per et, cu mei nibh erant inermis. Ne quo erant commodo sadipscing. Mei delenit tibique aliquando no, vim ex omnis vocibus scriptorem. Reque aperiam hendrerit et per, sit suas vivendo corrumpit in. Ius ei falli doming periculis. Nam quis iuvaret at. Impedit minimum similique ei pri, graeco interpretaris eu ius, dolor probatus scribentur in qui. Duo aliquam omittam voluptaria no. Vel enim hendrerit persecuti ne. Sed no idque fastidii neglegentur. Everti accusamus deterruisset eos ut, an sea feugiat alienum rationibus. Duo ex graece gloriatur, lorem appetere inimicus sed eu, autem sanctus in ius. No lorem altera qualisque eum, id eum labore necessitatibus, sit no diceret pertinax partiendo. At pri hinc solet voluptatum, ut debitis intellegam vix. Decore ridens comprehensam sea id, ius aperiam delicatissimi no. Quas molestie ei his, in has augue equidem adipisci.
             </div><!--End Content-->             
             </div><!--End Content Section-->



          </div> <!--End Network feed-->
        </div><!--End Feed Content-->
    </div><!--End Center-->
```

The css:

```
.center {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:100%;
    float:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#999;
    position:relative;
}
#contentSection {
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    display:block; 
    background-color:green;
}

/*----- Show me Button-----*/

#filterbutton[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
[for="filterbutton"] {
    position: absolute;
    top:4px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #DDD;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Sans Serif";
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    background: #EEE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F9F9F9), color-stop(100%, #DDD));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#DDD', GradientType=0);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%); 
}
[for="filterbutton"]:hover {
    color: #444444;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-color: #BBB;
    background: #CCC;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F9F9F9), color-stop(100%, #CCC));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#CCC', GradientType=0);
}
[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked {
    color:#FFA317;
}

#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    color:#3CC;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

#content {
    margin: 0; display:inline-block;
    position:relative; bottom:0;
    padding: 0; 
    padding-bottom:170px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.borderline {
    width:100%; display:block;
    border-bottom:#000 solid 1px;
    padding-top:37px; top:0; 
}
```

And the js:

```
var height = 0;
var minHeight = 200;
$("#content2").parent().siblings().each(function () {
    height = height + $(this).height();
});
// for when the document is loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowheight = $(window).height() - 100;
    $(".center").height();
    $(".center").css("min-height", minHeight + height + "px");
    var newHeight = $(".center").height() - height;
    $("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight - 0 + "px");
});

// for the window resize
$(window).resize(function () {
    var windowheight = $(window).height() - 100;
    $(".center").height(windowheight);
    $("#content2").height($("#content2").parent().height());
    var newHeight = $(".center").height() - height;
    $("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight - 0 + "px");
});

function toggleContent() {
  // Get the DOM reference
  var e = document.getElementById("content");
  // Toggle 
  e.style.display =="block" ? e.style.display="none" : 
e.style.display ="block"; 
}
```

So far I can resize the `scrollable-div`, but I can't figure out how to also resize the scrollbar without getting it cut-off at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/a5pcctrz/1/

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: resize the native scrollbar? it's not possible. the native scrollbars always take some space of the html element.

Comment: I would like to re-size a centered scrollable div and it's scrollbar depending on the size. Don't confuse it for the native browser scrollbar. Check out my fiddle for more info.

Comment: If you want the scrollbar to take the space of both the green section and also the white section you show/hide, you'll need to set the parent  of those sections to be scrollable, not just the green section

Comment: The white  section is supposed to be a dropdown of filters, and the the green section is for the scrollable content. So when you click on the white section (filters) the height and scrollbars should adjust accordingly.

Comment: Can you add the ids from your fiddle into your question? It's really hard to tell which sections you are trying to change / fix

Comment: I added the code in question. I'm trying to change the center section porimarily the green scrollable section called #Content-Section.